# Postibility to use Unlocked iphone for Developement

Tags: iphone

I was living in INDIA, and I got a iPhone Device from USA (provider AT&T). I need to use it for development.In this regard I have couple questions,

1. If I unlock the mobile, is it works for the development?
2. If I use my local provider sim to that iPhone, for that Do we need to unlock the mobile?

Please suggest me,

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Comment: Well, are you still in India?

Comment: @BoltClock, Yes I was still in INDIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your local SIM for unlocking iPhone, I have used Airtel SIM for unlocking the device we use in our office for development purpose. You still need to create developer account in Apple’s developer program by paying $99 annually, only then will you be able to use iPhone for development purpose.

You will find all the details here.

[Getting started with iPhone development](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)

Comment: Good morning. I had account already. Thanks for your quick reply, let me test it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register in Apple Developer's program ($99 via Fax after online registration) at http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/ and get Key for your device to test your apps in the device.

I have tried to do everything online. But Apple online store does not support direct payment. Hence, they ask to fax registration and card (for payment) details and it would take another week or so before you get the final confirmation via email.

Answer (score 0):

Unlocked devices still work for development. I can't guarantee that your local SIM card will work though, even if the device is unlocked.